# Is there any way to access a hostname containing an underscore?

Tags: linux, browser, hostname, url

I have this weird problem. I need to access a website that contains an underscore from Linux. The hostname is invalid and Linux does treat it as such.

The problem is that access from Windows seems to work just fine and therefore the admin won't fix it.

Is there any way to access such site?

EDIT:
The hostname is: `_nyx.isthereanydeal.com`

`host` works

`ping` and browsers don't work, I have tried both un-encoded and encoded versions of the hostname

Comment: Did you try to use the hex value instead (url encoded)?

Comment: Does hostname resolution work? Then you could at least access the website via IP if there isn't any virtual host depending on the actual host name.

Comment: @scai `host` works, `ping` and browsers don't, and the problem it's one sub-hostname, so yeah virtual hosts are present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can find the IP with `host`, add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file with a new name to the same IP.

## `/etc/hosts`

```
198.100.51.37  u_nyx.isthereanydeal.com
```

Then:

```
$ ping -c 1 u_nyx.isthereanydeal.com
PING u_nyx.isthereanydeal.com (198.100.51.37): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 198.100.51.37: icmp_seq=0 ttl=48 time=69.157 ms

--- u_nyx.isthereanydeal.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 69.157/69.157/69.157/0.000 ms
```